# Display timerpickerdialog within a fragment using Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fragment, timepickerdialog

I have followed the xamarin Timepicker tutorial [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/time_picker) to create a `Timepickerdialog` within an `Activity`. It works great.

I need to to do the same in a `fragment` but have failed to make it work.
Can someone please show me how to do it using a fragment? Any guildelines or links or advice.

I'm using `Xamarin Andriod`.
Thank you in advanced.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/timeDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
<Button android:id="@+id/pickTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change the time"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
private TextView time_display;
private Button pick_button;    
private int hour;
private int minute;    
const int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "Main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Capture our View elements
        time_display = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.timeDisplay);
        pick_button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.pickTime);

        // Add a click listener to the button
        pick_button.Click += (o, e) => ShowDialog (TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        // Get the current time
        hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;

        // Display the current date
        UpdateDisplay ();
}

// Updates the time we display in the TextView
private void UpdateDisplay ()
{
        string time = string.Format ("{0}:{1}", hour, minute.ToString ().PadLeft (2, '0'));
        time_display.Text = time;
}

private void TimePickerCallback (object sender, TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
{
        hour = e.HourOfDay;
        minute = e.Minute;
        UpdateDisplay ();
}

protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog (int id)
{
        if (id == TIME_DIALOG_ID)
                return new TimePickerDialog (this, TimePickerCallback, hour, minute, false);

        return null;
}
```

**Fragment.cs**

```
//Everything same as Activity
//updated the following:

time_display = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.timeDisplay);
pick_button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.pickTime);

protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id)
{
    if (id == TIME_DIALOG_ID)
        return new TimePickerDialog(this.Activity, TimePickerCallback, hour, minute, false);

    return null;
}
```

**Result:**

Error 1.The name 'ShowDialog' does not exist in the current context.

Error 2.Fragement.OnCreateDialog(int)': no suitable method found to override.

Comment: can you post your fragment code which you have tried this is activity you copied from tutorial.

Comment: Activity and fragment both are same. You can use the same codes for the fragment. Instead of "this" try "this.Activity".

Comment: @Hari_krish4.  I have updated the question and added the `this.activity` and `view.FindViewbyId` but got error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this set of code to show the TimePickerDialog.

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this.Activity, TimePickerCallback, hour, minute, false);
                timePickerDialog.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks . I had to remove overrride OnCreateDialog method. And add your code on button click.